# Redeploying war file does not update all classes

Tags: java, tomcat

I am redeploying a huge war file with the help of `Tomcat Manager` . After redeploying , changes are not reflected in the newly deployed war file as expected. After some debugging , I found that the class files in the deployed app are not updated. I check this as their Date Modified was not updated although that of my webapp folder was. Can someone help me out with this to understand why the new files are not uploaded and how can I get new files deployed? thanks.

Comment: What types of change you are talking about? For example changes in the class member variables or method signatures or adding new classes are not supported by default to be redefined. For these changes you should undeploy/deploy or use some extra tools such as JRebel or so.

Comment: @STaefi I have introduced some new variables to class file . I am undeploying the previous war file and then uploading the new one.

Comment: If you want to find out why `tomcat` shows such behavior you should read the documentation, but if you need not to undeploy/deply you may want to go for a some tools as I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @STaefi . I will check them .

Answer (score 0):

Remove your target folder where the .class files being created then clean the project once, after that create war.
Then deploy the updated war.
Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you should undeploy the old war file before deploying the new one.

Comment: You could try another way:
Step 1: Go to the webapps folder in your tomcat folder.
Step 2: Delete folder and war file of application which you want to deploy the new one.
Step 3: Copy new war file to this folder and wait for a moment. After that, recheck again.

Comment: I really want to avoid the copy-paste solution. Do you have any idea other than that .

Comment: I recommend using continuous integration tool to deploy application, such as Jenkins or Hudson. It's quite easy to set up and really helpful for deployment phase.

Comment: @TuanNguyenAnhI ok . Thanks . I will try them.